# Class 'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action' not found

Tags: php, magento, frameworks, action, mamp

I'm running Magento v2.2.2 on MAMP (PHP 7.0.33), and am trying to debug a third party module that deals with tracking numbers.

The full error that shows in my MAMP/logs/php_error.log when I try to run the module is as follows:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/Orderinfo/Details/Controller/Index/index.php on line 20
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/Orderinfo/Details/Controller/Index/index.php:0
```

Here is what Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/Orderinfo/Details/Controller/Index/index.php looks like:

```
namespace Orderinfo\Details\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $_productloader;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct...(and so forth)
```

The weird thing is, the command setup:di:compile runs just fine (it also fails to compile as expected when I modify the above line to say something like `class Index extends \Bogus\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.)

I've confirmed that the Framework/App/Action/Action.php file/class exists in `magento/lib/internal/Magento`, `magento/vendor/magento`, and `magento/app/code/Magento`. I also modified the .htacess of those directories to grant all access.

I'm pretty lost, if anyone has ever encountered this problem before and could give me some other things to try, that'd be awesome.

Thank you!

Comment: Remove Last word Action in class.

Comment: That gives me basically the same thing:  `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\Framework\App\Action' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/Orderinfo/Details/Controller/Index/index.php on line 20`

Comment: After deploying the module remove the var/di and var/generation folders and recompile di, it should be working.

Comment: I tried recompiling after deleting the magento/generated directory (in Magento 2.2.2, var/di and var/generation are replaced by magento/generated), but am still getting the same error. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I think this is not working on the magento2.2.2 version. I have found this on
the latest version of magento2.
```https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/1406```  -- Fixes issue with reading store config for the store with code of 'default'